# Which Tier the method runs

Tags: axapta

How to check witch tier method/code runs?

```
static server client void check()
{;
    info('Tier' + [...] ? 'client' : 'server');
}
```

what should be in `[...]`?

so we can call it from

```
static server void checkServer()
{;
    Class1::check();
}

static client void checkClient()
{;
    Class1::check();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static server client void check()
{
    ;

    info('Tier ' + (!isRunningOnServer() ? 'client' : 'server'));
}
```